# Colorbar 2D Histogram Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to realize a colorbar for a 2D Histogram in Python.

Here is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


mean=[0,0]
cov=[[1,1],[1,2]]
x,y = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean,cov,10000).T

fig=plt.figure()
ax=plt.axes()

cax=ax.hist2d(x,y,bins=30,cmap="Blues")
cb=fig.colorbar(cax)
cb.ax.set_label("counts in bin")

plt.show()
```

But here I get the error message:

> AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'autoscale_None'

What am I doing wrong?
I want to to this object oriented and thus I want to use the methods of ax and fig rather than using the functions of plt.

I hope somebody can help me...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`ax.hist2d`](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.hist2d.html) returns a tuple:

> The return value is `(counts, xedges, yedges, Image)`.

You only need the image for your colorbar:

```
cb=fig.colorbar(cax[3])
```